# Validating GPS Coordinates on asp

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to validate a GPS cordinate input using regularExpressionValidator in asp. My input is of the form (lat,long) I want to validate the textbox to allow only -90 to 90 on the lat and -180 to 180 on the long. Is there way I can achieve this.? It must also accept a comma in between the lat and long.
Thank you

Comment: Something like this might get you pretty close: ^(\-?[0-90](\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?[0-180](\.\d+)?)$

Comment: It fails, the errorMessage gets displayed

Answer (score 0):

This might help... [lat long validation regex](http://forums.asp.net/t/1557310.aspx)